# Bash alias not saving beyond one session?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash alias for traversing through a few folders, but the alias does not save after I close terminal.

I've already saved the alias in the .bashsrc file and have also have run the command . ~/.bashsrc.

Here's what I've done:

```
sudo nano .bashsrc
```

Inside bashsrc:

```
alias x = 'cd Documents/Photos/Family'
```

And then saved and exit.

```
. ~/.bashsrc
```

The alias works in that terminal window, but shows "command not found" if I restart terminal or open a new tab.

Comment: The file you want is called '.bashrc', not '.bashsrc'.

Comment: I have no idea why it shows "command not found" rather than "bash: alias: x: not found" "bash: alias: =: not found", but you can't have spaces around the `=`

Comment: @MichaelAlbers: Since the OP appears to source his file manually, he can call it as he wants.

Comment: @user1934428 - Yes he can.  But if he calls it something non-standard it won't be sourced automatically when he restarts his terminal.  So "that other guy" is correct.

Comment: @StephenC : Even if we call it`.bashrc`, which for sure  *is* reasonable, it would not be sourced automatically, if the Terminal starts the the shell via `bash --login`, as many Terminals applications are doing. That's why it is a good idea to source .bashrc manually from .bash_profile.

Comment: "I'm trying to make a bash alias". Don't. Use a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should prefer setting your changes in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

```
alias x='cd Documents/Photos/Family'
```

Also, remember aliases won’t be exported to subshells and while using this alias you always need to be present in the directory where `Documents` is present. I guess your `Documents` directory is present in home, so it would be better if you do something like:

```
alias x="cd "$HOME"/Documents/Photos/Family"
```

Just add this line to the end of both the files and save.

In simple language there are two types of shells for your case, login and non-login interactive shell.

Before starting of a login shell, `.bash_profile` is sourced and before starting of a non-login shell `.bashrc` is sourced.

So you should add your changes in both.

If you are on macOS, `.bashrc` is next to useless for your case. MacOS would treat every shell you open in terminal as a login shell. Although there are some exceptions which i don’t remember.

As mentioned by David in the comments, in some distros `~/.bash_profile` is just `~/.profile` (e.g. Debian, openSUSE, etc).

Comment: Worth mentioning that on some distros `~/.bash_profile` is just `~/.profile` (e.g. Debian, openSUSE, etc...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sure, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: It's more of an informational. Given the problem the OP was having, if he looks and finds no `~/.bash_profile`, knowing it can also be named `~/.profile` could prevent bewilderment again... `:)`

Comment: This worked! I was working on a Mac, so as you pointed out .bashrc is pretty useless. So I added the line to .bash_profile and it works perfectly now. Thanks!